# Angular Form built-in validators error object-keys

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

Where can I get the the **error object keys** list of the [built-in Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators)?

For example, if a field uses the `required` built-in validator, then I can check:

`form.get('myField').hasError('required')`

but not all the error object keys have the same name as the validator.

For example, if I use the `maxLength` validator, then the following will **not** work:

`form.get('myField').hasError('maxLength')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to check those values looking directly at the source code:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/validators.ts

---

In my specific case, the object key error for the `maxLength` validator is `maxlength` (with lower case L).

I figured it out by looking its implementation in the source code, currently:

```
  static maxLength(maxLength: number): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const length: number = control.value ? control.value.length : 0;
      return length > maxLength ?
          {'maxlength': {'requiredLength': maxLength, 'actualLength': length}} :
          null;
    };
  }
```

so I'm using:

`form.get('myField').hasError('maxlength')`

Answer (score 0):

You can also print the error object to the browser console to see the keys of those validators that currently raised an error.

```js
addressForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    zipCode: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(10),
    ]),
});

get zipCode() { return this.addressForm.get('zipCode')!; }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.zipCode.valueChanges.subscribe(() => console.log(this.zipCode.errors));
}
```